# Miss code g-recaptcha in php

Tags: php

well i have change this php to work with google recaptcha and i tank so i miss something here in the code can some one help me to solve that please.
I Have Implement My Self But I Miss Something In Integration Can Some One Help To Solve That
the code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title><?php echo $settings["title"]?></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/css/myCssClass.css" media="screen">



  <style>

  .color-title{
    color:<?php echo $settings["title_color"];?>;
  }
  .color-subtitle{
    color:<?php echo $settings["subtitle_color"];?>;
  }
  .color-background-body{
    <?php if($settings["background_image_selected"]=="true") {?>
      background-image: url(<?php echo $settings["background_image"];?>);
      <?php } else{ ?>
    background-color:<?php echo $settings["background_color"];
    }?>;
  }
  </style>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body class="color-background-body">
  <div class ="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="text-center color-title"><?php echo $settings["title"];?></h1>
    <h3 class="text-center color-subtitle"><?php echo $settings["subtitle"];?></h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 hidden-xs">
        <!-- Insert your left vertical google ad Code below this comment-->
        <?php echo $settings["left_vertical_ad"];?>
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8 text-center">
      <div class="top-banner">
        <!-- Insert your top horizontal google ad Code below this comment (Recommended size 728x90)-->
        <?php echo $settings["top_horizontal_ad"];?>
    </div>


      <div><strong><p class="alert alert-info">Your possible rewards <?php echo $rewards["reward_list_html"]; ?></p></strong></div>
      <div>
        <strong><p>Earning bitcoins is simple:</p></strong>
      </div>
      <?php echo $view['main']['result_html']; ?>
      <?php echo $view['main']['ref_link']; ?>
      <!-- Insert your second horizontal google ad Code below this comment (Recommended size 320x100)-->
      <?php echo $settings["middle_horizontal_ad"]; ?>
      <form method="Post">
        <div >
          <div><label>Insert your email:</label>
           <center><center><input name="username" id="username" class="form-control text-center" type="text" style="width: 450px; placeholder="Enter your email"></div>
          </div><br>
           <div></center>
     <center>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld_7RwTAAAAAB3OYJE8jJtqcbg-PQ3STA-VU8G7"></div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 
    </form>
 </div>
  </body>

            
          <br>
          <!-- Insert your rectangle google ad Code below this comment (Recommended size 300x250)-->
          <?php echo $settings["bottom_horizontal_ad"];?>
          <div id="description">
            <strong><p><?php echo $settings["main_content"];?></p></strong>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 hidden-xs zeta">
        <!-- Insert your right vertical google ad Code below this comment-->
        <?php echo $settings["right_vertical_ad"];?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer><strong><p class="text-center">Copyright &#169; 2016 <?php echo $settings["title"];?> <a href=<?php echo $settings["contact_mail"];?>>Contact us</a></p></strong></footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tanks for the help i have solve all ready the bug tanks all for the help